# Java Equivalent of C#'s Action Type in terms of efficiency. Java 8 or Pre-Java 8?

Tags: java, c#, selenium

Does Java have anything similar to C#'s Action type? Is Java 8 or Pre-Java 8 the way to go? Why or why not? I'm trying to avoid going down any rabbit holes. Please help me understand my options...

Statement:

```
Driver.NoWait(() => links = rowFindElements(ByLinkText(title)));
```

Methods:

```
 public static void NoWait(Action action)
 {
      TurnOffWait();
      action();
      TurnOnWait();

 }

 public static void TurnOnWait()
 {
      Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
 }

 public static void TurnOffWait()
 {
      Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
 }
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Nick Y and a programmer at the office (who told me the history of Java pragmatics vs Java traditionalists). This is the outcome of my findings:

*Feature Menu Class 1st Way **Post Java 8***

```
public class FeatureMenu 
{
    static WebElement sideTab;


    public static void Expand() 
    {
        try
        {
            Iframe.Default.SwitchTo();

            Driver.NoWait(() -> sideTab = Driver.Instance.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.wijmo-wijsplitter-v-panel1-collapsed")));

            sideTab.click();
            Log.Info("Feature Menu Expanded.");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error("[EXCEPTION CAUGHT] : FeatureMenu.Expand()");
            throw(e);
        }
    }
}
```

*Feature Menu 2nd Way **Pre Java 8***

```
public class FeatureMenu 
{
    static WebElement sideTab;
    public static void Expand() 
    {
        try
        {
            Iframe.Default.SwitchTo();

            Driver.NoWait( new Driver.Action(){ public void apply(){
            sideTab = Driver.Instance.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.wijmo-wijsplitter-v-panel1-collapsed"));
                                        }
        });

            sideTab.click();
            Log.Info("Feature Menu Expanded.");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error("[EXCEPTION CAUGHT] : FeatureMenu.Expand()");
            throw(e);
        }
    }
}
```

*Driver Class that can be used with either approach*

```
public class Driver
{

    public static WebDriver Instance;

    public static String BaseAddress(String baseAddress)
    {   
        return baseAddress;
    }

    public static void Initialize(String driverType)
    {
        Instance = new FirefoxDriver();

        Instance.manage().window().maximize();

        TurnOnWait();
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface Action {
        void apply();

    }

    public static void NoWait(Action action)
    {
        TurnOffWait();
        action.apply();
        TurnOnWait();
    }

    public static void TurnOffWait()
    {
        Instance.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static void TurnOnWait()
    {
        Instance.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try something like Runnable: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, however based on the documentation I don't think this would be efficient for what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get closer to the most recent C# version you would want to use Java 8 (not pre-Java 8)

Java 8 has lambdas and functional interfaces which can get you very close to how things are done in C#. Google "functional interface java". There is a lot good information out there.

In the context of your specific question think about functional interfaces in java as delegates in C#.

```
public delegate void Action()
```

can be mimicked in java 8 as

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Action() {
    void apply();
}
```

With this in mind, here is the simple usage of Action interface and lambda

```
public class MainWithAction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        noWait(() -> doSomething());
    }

    public static void noWait(Action action) {
        turnOffWait();
        action.apply();
        turnOnWait();
    }

    public static void doSomething() { /* do something */ }
    public static void turnOnWait() { /* skipped */ }
    public static void turnOffWait() { /* skipped */ }
}
```

It is not a requirement to use [@FunctionalInterface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) annotation but it helps compiler to generate error messages in certain cases.
`apply()` method name can be changed to anything else it is more of a convention thing.

Java 8 has a few predefined functional interfaces in package `java.util.function` however it appears that there is nothing that returns void and takes no parameters so you would need to have your own. Read more here:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/276859/what-is-the-name-of-a-function-that-takes-no-argument-and-returns-nothing

You may want to consider having NoWaitAction interface which can be a more appropriate name for your scenario instead of a generic Action interface. It's up to you.

Having said all that I am moving to more interesting point of going down the rabbit hole.

Your particular use case may not map 100% into the java code. Let's try to convert this line.

> ```
> Driver.NoWait(() => links = rowFindElements(ByLinkText(title)));
> ```

What caught my eye here is the `links` variable. It does look like a local variable to me. If this is not the case then the bellow is irrelevant, but may still trigger some thoughts.

For the sake of this exercise I am going to assume that `links` is a local variable of `List` of `String`s type and `rowFindElements` takes `String` parameter and returns a `List` of `String`s

Here is one way of converting this into java (with NoWaitAction as an example of my above point):

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface NoWaitAction {
    void apply();
}
```

and the meat

```
public class MainNoWaitAction {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<String> links = new ArrayList<>();
       String title = "title";

       noWait(() -> links.addAll(rowFindElements(title)));
   }

   public static void noWait(NoWaitAction action) {
       turnOffWait();
       action.apply();
       turnOnWait();
   }

   public static void turnOnWait() { /* skipped */ }
   public static void turnOffWait() { /* skipped */ }

   public static List<String> rowFindElements(String title) {
       return new ArrayList<>(); // populate the list
   }
}
```

There are various other ways of doing it, but the main point here is that the following will not compile

```
    noWait(() -> links = rowFindElements(title));
```

Why? Read this answer for example
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4732617/5947137

**Update 1**

Based on OP comments I would like to suggest another approach

```
public class MainNoWaitAction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> links;
        Object otherVariable;

        String title = "title";

        links = noWait(() -> rowFindElements(title));
        otherVariable = noWait(() -> createAnObject());
    }

    public static <T> T noWait(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        turnOffWait();
        try {
            return supplier.get();
        } finally {
            turnOnWait();
        }
    }

    private static void turnOnWait() { /* skipped */ }
    private static void turnOffWait() { /* skipped */ }

    private static List<String> rowFindElements(String title) {
        return new ArrayList<>(); // populate the list
    }

    private static Object createAnObject() {
        return new Object();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Nick thank you for the information and resources. I can confirm `noWait(() -> links = rowFindElements(title));` does not compile. I'll keep you updated with my findings.

Comment: I followed your comment, however I am having difficulty with the following statement `Driver.NoWait(() -> sideTab = Driver.Instance.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.wijmo-wijsplitter-v-panel1-collapsed")));`
Also, I'm still reading the resources you supplied.

Comment: @PhiL, you are welcome. Additionally depending on your requirements if you are not constrained with using java as a language take a look at [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/). This is one of the newer jvm based languages that compiles into java byte code and runs in java vm but feels very much like C# to program in.

Comment: @PhiL, it's hard to suggest something good without seeing the big picture. If you make sideTab a class variable (instead of local variable) it will compile and work, but may not be the best in terms of structuring your code.

Comment: sideTab is of the WebElement class. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: I am very much shooting in the dark here, but I posted another way as an update.

Comment: thanks. I updated the question. Feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write code the same way in Java :

```
public interface Action {
    void apply();
}

public static void DoSomething(Action action)
{
    action.apply();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    DoSomething(() -> System.out.println("test action"));

}
```

Comment: I had upgrade my project to 1.8 in order to use this. I'm currently integrating it with my framework. I'll update this thread with my findings.

Comment: This approach is throwing an error: `Local Variable defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final `